# Iterate through an API-array, data.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, api, iteration

I tried to get some help yesterday but I didnt have much coverage of the real problem, nor did I give to much of my code but here we go again.  Don't flame me for my poor understanding of coding please :).

I'm trying to loop through an API GET response, that's in jSON. But I get stuck at the forEach loop as you can see in the code. Here's the error-message: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.forEach is not a function
at index.js:26

Here's the entire javascript code:

```
"use strict";

window.addEventListener('load', () => {

  let form = document.getElementById('search-form');
  let content = document.getElementById('content');
  let searchField = document.getElementById('search');

  form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    search(searchField.value);
  });
});

/**
 * Makes a request to https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/{query} .
 * @param {string} query The user’s search query
 * @param {HTMLElement} content The <tbody> element that the result will be printed to
*/

function search(query, container) {
  window.fetch('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=' + encodeURIComponent(query) + "&apiKey=blabla")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      data.forEach(item => {
        createArticlesHolders(item, container);
      })
    });
}

function createArticlesHolders(newsData, container) {

  let card = document.createElement('div');
  card.className= "card";
  card.style.width = "20rem";
  content.appendChild(card);

  let cardTitle = createElement("h5");
  cardTitle.className = "card-title";
  cardTitle.textContent = newsData.title;
  card.appendChild(cardTitle);

  let cardImg = document.createElement("img");
  cardImg.className = "card-img-top";
  cardImg.setAttribute('src', newsData.urlToImage);
  card.appendChild(cardImg);

}

$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#myInput').trigger('focus')
})
```

What I'm trying to do is that, when someone searchs for a countrycode in the searchbox, some of the top news shall appear for the country. Then the code is supposed to create elements with bootstrap classes.

Here's the console.log(data);

[image]

Comment: The Array.prototype.forEach() works only on array type, be sure your api return the data as an array, you may have to parse it to the right format regarding of the response.

Comment: Can you include the output of console.log(data) ?

Comment: @Ank here you go.

Comment: The screenshot has just clipped off something important at the top: the array is in a *property* of `data`, not `data` itself, which is a plain object.

Comment: @Ank {status: "ok", totalResults: 34, articles: Array(20)} Sorry

Comment: So do `data.articles.forEach`

Comment: Did you try this ^^^^ ?

Comment: @trincot I did not since the0ffh's solution worked just fine! Thanks anyway <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot iterate over `json` using `forEach`. For this purpose, you could use e.g. `Object.keys()` or `for...in` loop - iteration over top level keys, i.e.:

```
...
keys = Object.keys(data);
keys.forEach(key => {
    createArticlesHolders(data[key], container);
})
...
```

or

```
...
for (let key in data) {
    createArticlesHolders(data[key], container);
}
...
```

Edit:
Not sure if `data` is `json` or an `array` - if the second one, you should, obviously, iterate over it before.

Comment: I seem to be getting somewhere with this, thank you so far.

Comment: But now I got an new error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND what does this mean?

Comment: Can you post a little more of the error log? There should be an indication what file is unable to load.

Comment: I got it, it's all good now. Thank you for the simple lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

The data is a regular object that doesn't have forEach method. You should iterate through the property of the object.

```js
let data = {
  "articles": [
    {
      "author": "Author 1"
    },
    {
      "author": "Author 2"
    },
    {
      "author": "Author 3"
    }
  ]
}

data.articles.forEach((obj) => {
  console.log(obj.author)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include the print for `console.log(data)`. But regardless, just read the error message, `data.forEach` is not a function; therefore, `data` is not an array.